# jQuery AJAX - Set PHP Session variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to store a variable across an entire session so that when a user closes a promotional bar it stays closed and doesn't pop back up every time they navigate to a new page.

On page load I have the following:

```
$.ajax
({ 
  url: 'promo.php',
  type: 'post',
  data : formData,
  success: function(result)
  {
    alert(result);
  }

});
```

The formData isn't too important right now as it isn't used.*

**promo.php:**

```
<?php

  if (isset($_SESSION['promoBar'])) {

    echo $_SESSION['promoBar'];

  }
  else {

    $_SESSION['promoBar'] = "closed";
    echo "does not exist";

  }

?>
```

The idea is that on page load it will check if the `$_SESSION['promoBar']` variable exists, and if it does, return it's value.  Otherwise set a value.

Currently the alert always displays `does not exist`.  I was expecting it to display `does not exist` the first time and then `closed` each time I navigate to a new page.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Where you are setting the session `$_SESSION['promoBar']` and if so where do you have `session_start` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...
Use "session_start" before check

```
session_start();

  if (isset($_SESSION['promoBar'])) {

    echo $_SESSION['promoBar'];

  }
  else {

    $_SESSION['promoBar'] = "closed";
    echo "does not exist";

  }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! Might be worth editing your code from "start_session" to "session_start"

Comment: check it and let me know